# Number of Combinations of Connected Bipartite Graphs

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

Given two sets of vertices $U$ (size $n$) and $V$ (size $m$), how many possibilities of set of edges $E$ exist that make the bipartite graph $G = (U, V, E)$ connected?

Obviously there are $2^{n m}$ different set of edges but many will be disconnected.

Comment: It's at least $2^{(n-1)(m-1)}$, If this is enough for you to see is very big.

Comment: I know that it is very big. But how big?

Comment: I think in this big range $2^{(m-1)(n-1)}$ is somehow precise, but you looking for the exact number? Can I ask you what's your original problem?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to solve Project Euler 434. I know that a grid truss is rigid if the bipartite graph formed from it, is connected. Form the bipartite graph by having U being all rows and V being all columns, add an edge for every diagonal member in (row, col). http://www.iust.ac.ir/files/cefsse/pg.cef/Contents/chapter_3.pdf , page 98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is was given by David Eisenstadt in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631590/461597) to my question.

The answer can be computed by starting with the fully connected bipartite graph and evaluating the Tutte polynomial at (1,2).

While I don't fully understand everything about this problem, the intuitive reasoning is as follows:

Start with the fully connected-graph. The Contraction-Deletion Algorithm and the Tutte polynomial at (1,1) give the number of possible spanning trees. But we are actually not interested in the number of spanning trees but also along all the still-connected graphs along the paths to get to the spanning trees.

## Note:

If you can explain this further, either add your own answer, or edit mine. If you add your own answer, I will accept yours.

Comment: This is hard problem, otherwise someone here or in SO would provide a complete answer. But point of my comment was if you want to brute force on something like this, you should not do it.

Comment: And you don't have to, because the Tutte polynomial gives you the answer! Also I never wanted to run anything on the set of combinations, I just wanted to know the size. Calculating this is far from brute force. One implementation I found gives me this for n=100, m=100 in about a second.